# Interview question: Even and odd elements at even and odd positions (keep elements order)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

The following question asked in an interview:

Given an array. The task is to arrange the array such that:

- odd elements occupy the odd positions and even elements occupy the even positions.

**-  The order of elements must remain same.**

- Consider zero-based indexing.
- After printing according to conditions, if remaining, print the remaining elements as it is.

Example:

Input:
Arr = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Output:
Arr= 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9

Is there a solution with no constant space (i.e O(1)) and in O(N) time ?

Comment: `O(1)` is not no extra space. It's constant extra space. The amount of extra space needed doesn't depend on the input, but it doesn't have to be zero.

Comment: Removed the C++ tag as this can be answered generically.

Comment: Well if your original array contained only even elements then you would need at least N additional space to store the output no?

Comment: A concrete example (or two) would be helpful for understanding the expectations.

Comment: You describe an artificial problem and ask for the solution. That is not how StackOverflow is meant to be used. Please explain what problem you have with this. I believe that the question is so unclear that answering it would require several assumptions. Note that interviewers might actually be looking for that. I.e. you might actually fail, if you give an assertive answer, because you were expected to point out the shortcoming of the question first and then propose a most likely interpretation, which then you can answer.

Comment: If you search in your browser for the subject of your posting, you'll find [references](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/even-numbers-even-index-odd-numbers-odd-index/) that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Like many good interview-question, it contains ambiguity which needs resolved. Unfortunately, that makes it a bad [SO] question.

Comment: @Prune Algorithm on GeekForGeeks doesn't provide solution to this task because here `the order must remain same` which is not always the case in the aforementioned refrence.

Comment: Ah -- you're right.  *that* one is not a stable partition.  However, the technique is easily adapted, and other solutions do provide stability.

Comment: I update to constant space

Comment: @user3668129 Can you provide examples? - input and output. 2 of them would be good

Comment: I add an example

Comment: Is the starting array guaranteed to be given with all evens on one side and all odds on the other side?

Comment: No, they can be mixed

Comment: There's still a critical missing piece of information. What goes into output array elements when there are no more elements of that evenness/oddness? E.g. if the input is [2,4,1,3] then the output is simply [2,1,4,3], but what if the input is [2,4,1,3,5,7]? If the critical piece of missing information is "fill extra entries with -1", then the output would be [2,1,4,3,-1,5] and the remaining elements printed at the end would be "7". But that's making an assumption about the requirements. The real requirement needs specified.

Comment: @phonetagger I don't believe you need to know that to answer the time and space complexity.  The answer is 'no', the requirements are in conflict with each other.  You can't do swaps and preserve order, so you will store the array elements that get bumped in a separate array that will be dependent on the input (N/2).  Without preserving order you just need a single temp variable.

Comment: @Jeff Yes I think you're right, if the answer to the question is simply whether you can or can't develop an algorithm in O(1) space and O(n) time. I think if you can loosen the time complexity, you can do it in O(1) space, but at O(n*log n) time (or something like that) since you have to ripple the not-yet-finalized elements up to fill the "hole" instead of just swapping.

Comment: Are we guaranteed to have an equal number of odd numbers and even numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If there's n/2 even elements and n/2 odd elements the solution can be very simple, keep an 'even pointer' and 'odd pointer' to the first even empty place in the new array, and the first odd empty place at the new array. than just go over the old array, fill elements at the right position, and don't forget to increase the pointer by 2;
If the number of odd elements is diffrenet than the even ones- u can disocover how much even and odd numners are at O(n), so again, the question is quite simple.